# What is a "launder stub"?

Tags: science

What is the meaning here of 'launder stub' in this summary from an abstract:

> The container is connected in parallel with a metal supply launder via transversal metal **launder stubs** respectively provided between the inlet and outlet openings of the container and the metal supply launder . On the other hand, the launder is provided with a dam or valve device by the outlet of the container  and another other dam or valve device between the two launder stubs"

[REMOVAL OF UNWANTED INCLUSIONS FROM METAL MELTS](https://www.onscope.com/ipowner/en/ip/ptca/02983006.html)

Comment: Where is this quote from? You need to add the name of the source to your question and (if it has one) include a link to it.

Comment: @Laurel Abstract sourced and edited in.

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of "launder stub" from the limited information above is best understood pictorially.

Hot (molten) metal is being introduced into a launder trough and thence, via launder 'stubs', into the 'container' which is 'connected in parallel'.

The setup is more complicated than below as there is a process occurring which removes impurities, but that diagram I have not found. However my diagram here shows the basics (from examining the text) of what a 'launder stub' is, which was the question.

**Launder Trough**  (from [Access Industrial](http://accessindustrial.com/portfolio/frp-weirs-scum-baffles/))

[image]

**Launder Stub** (my own diagram)

[image]

Comment: so you refer to stub here as a junction?

Comment: @Mahahasan No, the stub launder is a short launder which carries liquid from the supply launder to the final container.